# What is a GoAway Frame in Http2 and how is it linked to Redirects?

Tags: java, http, http-redirect, http2, java-9

I am aware of [HTTP/2 Client provided by Java 9](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/110) and while trying out the incubator module with the following code:

```
// Request builder
URI uri = new URI("http://www.stackoverflow.com/"); // using www.google.com gives me some payload with no exception
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(uri).GET().build();

// Client
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder().followRedirects(HttpClient.Redirect.ALWAYS).build();
System.out.println(httpClient.version());

// Response builder
HttpResponse response = httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandler.asString());

System.out.println("statusCode = " + response.statusCode()); // 200 for google.com
```

I received this as an output :

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: /192.168.0.2:60726: GOAWAY received
>   at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.Http2Connection.handleGoAway(Http2Connection.java:613)
>   at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.Http2Connection.handleConnectionFrame(Http2Connection.java:531)
>   at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.Http2Connection.processFrame(Http2Connection.java:466)
>   at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.internal.frame.FramesDecoder.decode(FramesDecoder.java:114)
>   at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.Http2Connection$FramesController.processReceivedData(Http2Connection.java:152)
>   at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.Http2Connection.asyncReceive(Http2Connection.java:425)
>   at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.AsyncSSLDelegate.upperRead(AsyncSSLDelegate.java:557)
>   at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.internal.common.Queue.put(Queue.java:73)
>   at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.AsyncSSLDelegate.asyncReceive(AsyncSSLDelegate.java:503)
>   at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.PlainHttpConnection.asyncRead(PlainHttpConnection.java:300)
>   at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.PlainHttpConnection$ReadEvent.handle(PlainHttpConnection.java:395)
>   at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.HttpClientImpl$SelectorManager.handleEvent(HttpClientImpl.java:438)
>   at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.HttpClientImpl$SelectorManager.run(HttpClientImpl.java:408)
> ```

Moving down the stack trace I could find `GOAWAY` listed as one of types of

```
jdk.incubator.http.internal.frame.Http2Frame
```

but then the internal class is not much documented to find exactly what does this type represent. I tried searching for the same on links from the JEPs as well, but couldn't find any.

***Q.*** What is a GoAway Frame? When and how is it used?

***Q.*** Why if I change my code to use a client without following redirects trying to GET "stackoverflow.com" I do not get the same exception?

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As set in the [specifications](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-quic-http-20#section-4.2.7),

> The GOAWAY frame (type=0x7) is used to initiate graceful shutdown of
> a connection by a server.

It is likely that the frame is sent by the server on the second connection, the one following the redirect.

Do all URLs at stackoverflow.com accept http/2 connections ? That does not seem to be the case when looking at the indicator of my HTTP/2-SPDY browser plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the doc. Coul you elaborate *frame is sent by the server on the second connection* why would that not happen at first and when I remove the following redirections does the server not try and redirect(since it results in 200 then)?

Comment: I was thinking of the following scenario: the first connection happens via http/2 which redirects to a (redirect) URL. The client then tries to access that URL via HTTP/2 however the server responding to requests on that URL does not support HTTP/2 => GOAWAY. If you instruct your http client to not follow redirects, it should never attempt to access the redirect URL (... and I do not understand how you get a 200 in that scenario)

Comment: seems the link is dead. I am getting errorCode in GOAWAY Frame. is there any mapping of error code and description?

Comment: What about the expression "go away" could be presented as "graceful" ?

Answer (score 4):

Redirect from HTTP/1.1 with Upgrade to HTTP/2 over TLS erroneously includes Upgrade header. This issue has been filed

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8198709